# Indexes in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

We have a table **users (userid, username, category, pincode)** in postgresql

If we create indexes like:

1. create index category_idx(category) on users;
2. create index category_pincode_idx(category, pincode) on users;

and query the table **users** as:

```
select * from users where category = somevalue;
```

which index will be applied?

Comment: The first index is redundant. Any query that can use the first index also can use the second. You might also want to read this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-examine.html

Comment: One more thing i would like to ask: If there is a table users (userid, username, category, pincode) whose primary key is (userid, category, pincode), then it is required/not to create an index on those primary key columns separately/as a whole.

Comment: When you define a primary key, Postgres automatically creates an unique index for that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-unique.html

Comment: So, it means there is no need to create an index explicitly on column pincode separately if its a part of primary key.

Comment: That's not what I said. If you have a query that has a condition **only** on pincode, it *might* make sense. Please do read the chapter about indexes in the manual

Comment: You also might read this website: http://use-the-index-luke.com it contains a lot of useful information on how indexes work.

Answer (score 3):

Executing the following statement will reveal which index the execution planner will pick depending on the current data set:

```
explain select * from users where category = somevalue;
```

Please be advised that the planner might even chose to not use the index if the amount of data does not warrant the use of an index because a full table scan over very few rows might be quicker.